# Which pair of functions satisfy f (N) ~g(N)?

Tags: math

Which pair of functions satisfy f (N)  ~g(N)?

1. (N + 1)(N + N) and 2N
2. (N + 1)(N + N) and N^3
3. log N + log 3N and 3 log N
4. 2^N and 2^N + N^2

I am unsure if the answer is 3 or 4. The two functions here are equally almost the same and the output of them is also almost the same when I put some values into them, but how do I know which one is the right one?

Comment: How is the `~` relation defined? is it `f(N) ~ g(N)  :<=>  O(f(n)) = O(g(n))` ?

Comment: How is this related to programming (or algorithms) in the first place?

Comment: The question dosen't say anything how the relation is defined.

Comment: This isn't really a SO question.  This would be a better fit for [cs.se] or maybe [math.se]

Comment: To at least give a hint (assuming it's about big-O notation): **The simple rule is that if two functions are added, the "heavier one" wins and the other one is ignored**. Another rule is that **constant factors don't matter**.  So, for example, `O(2^N) = O(2^N + N^2)` because `2^N` is "heavier" (grows faster) than `N^2`.

Comment: @Alex it's not about big-O. The tilde operator here indicates equivalent limits as N goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

f~g means f(x)/g(x) -> 1 as x->infinity (or equivalently, g(x)/f(x) -> 1 as x->infinity).

The answer is (4): (2^N+N^2)/(2^N) = 1 + N^2/2^N. The latter term (N^2/2^N) tends to 0 (quickly!) as N->infinity.

(3) is wrong because logN+log3N = 2logN+log3, so (logN+log3N)/3logN -> 2/3 as N->infinity.